# Merge free arrows with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm starting with TikZ, and basicaly what I'm trying to achieve is to draw what is shown in red in the next picture:

[image]

I think the solution is to use the help grid in order to point the line to the coordinate where I want to merge it with other, I tried for hours but it seems it's impossible for me :( can please anybody help me? Please find attached my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[bottom=25mm,top=25mm, left=30mm, right=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla, es-noshorthands, es-nosectiondot]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{datastore}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \backgroundpath{
    %  store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
 }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  font=\sffamily,
  every matrix/.style={ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=2cm,row sep=2cm},
  subsistema/.style={draw,thick,rounded corners,fill=white!20,inner sep=.3cm},
  adpredect/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split parts = 3,draw,thick,rounded corners,fill=white!20,inner sep=.3cm},
  click_OK/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=green!20},
  click_NOK/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=red!20},
  bypass/.style={subsistema,fill=yellow!20},
  datastore/.style={draw,very thick,shape=datastore,inner sep=.3cm},
  dots/.style={gray,scale=2},
  to/.style={->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,semithick,font=\sffamily\footnotesize},
  every node/.style={align=center}]

  % Position the nodes using a matrix layout
  \matrix{
    \node[subsistema] (preparobox) {bla\\ bla};
      \& \node[subsistema] (lectmot) {blablablablablablabla\\ blablablabla}; \& \\

    \& \node[datastore] (colamot) {blabla}; \& \\

    \node[subsistema] (parobox) {blablablabla\\ blablabla};
      \& \node[adpredect] (subs) {%
                      blablablablablablabla     \nodepart{two}
                      blablablablablablabla    \nodepart{three}
                      blablablablablablabla   \nodepart{four}
                      }; 
      \& \node[click_OK] (clickdetectado) {OK}; \\
      \& \node[click_NOK] (clicknodetectado) {NOK}; \& \node[bypass] (acc_bypass) {BYPASS}; \\
  };

  % Draw the arrows between the nodes and label them.
  \draw[to] (preparobox) -- node[midway,above] {blabla}
      node[midway,below] {blablablabla} (lectmot);
  \draw[to] (lectmot) -- node[midway,right] {bla} (colamot);
  \draw[to] (lectmot) to[bend left=50] node[midway,below] {bla} (preparobox);
  \draw[to] (colamot) --
      node[midway,right] {blablabla\\bla} (subs);
   \draw[to] (parobox) -- node[midway,above] {bla}
      node[midway,below] {blabla} (subs);
    \draw[to] (subs) -- node[midway,above] {blabla}
     node[midway,below] {blabla} (clickdetectado);
     \draw[to] (subs) -- node[midway,left] {blablabla\\blablablabla}
     (clicknodetectado);
     \draw[to] (clicknodetectado) -- node[midway,above] {blablablabla} node[midway,below] {blablabla} (acc_bypass);
     \draw[to] (clickdetectado) to [out = -50, in = -90, looseness=2.2] node[midway,above] {blablabla} node[midway,below] {blablabla} (parobox);
     %\draw[to] (acc_bypass) to [out = -50, in = -90, looseness=1.2] (parobox);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [image: Result]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[bottom=25mm,top=25mm, left=30mm, right=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla, es-noshorthands, es-nosectiondot]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, intersections}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{datastore}{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \backgroundpath{
    %  store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
 }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  font=\sffamily,
  every matrix/.style={ampersand replacement=\&,column sep=2cm,row sep=2cm},
  subsistema/.style={draw,thick,rounded corners,fill=white!20,inner sep=.3cm},
  adpredect/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split parts = 3,draw,thick,rounded corners,fill=white!20,inner sep=.3cm},
  click_OK/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=green!20},
  click_NOK/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=red!20},
  bypass/.style={subsistema,fill=yellow!20},
  datastore/.style={draw,very thick,shape=datastore,inner sep=.3cm},
  dots/.style={gray,scale=2},
  to/.style={->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,semithick,font=\sffamily\footnotesize},
  every node/.style={align=center}]

  % Position the nodes using a matrix layout
  \matrix{
    \node[subsistema] (preparobox) {bla\\ bla};
      \& \node[subsistema] (lectmot) {blablablablablablabla\\ blablablabla}; \& \\

    \& \node[datastore] (colamot) {blabla}; \& \\

    \node[subsistema] (parobox) {blablablabla\\ blablabla};
      \& \node[adpredect] (subs) {%
                      blablablablablablabla     \nodepart{two}
                      blablablablablablabla    \nodepart{three}
                      blablablablablablabla   \nodepart{four}
                      }; 
      \& \node[click_OK] (clickdetectado) {OK}; \\
      \& \node[click_NOK] (clicknodetectado) {NOK}; \& \node[bypass] (acc_bypass) {BYPASS}; \\
  };

  % Draw the arrows between the nodes and label them.
  \draw[to] (preparobox) -- node[midway,above] {blabla}
      node[midway,below] {blablablabla} (lectmot);
  \draw[to] (lectmot) -- node[midway,right] {bla} (colamot);
  \path (preparobox.south east) ++(-45:3pt) coordinate (preparo_se);
  \draw[semithick] (lectmot) to[bend left=50,in=135] node[midway,below] {bla}
      (preparo_se);
  \draw[semithick] ($(lectmot.south)!.6!(colamot.north)$) to[bend left=50,in=135]
      (preparo_se);
  \draw[to, shorten >=0pt] (preparo_se) -- (preparobox.south east);
  \draw[to] (colamot) --
      node[midway,right] {blablabla\\bla} (subs);
   \draw[to] (parobox) -- node[midway,above] {bla}
      node[midway,below] {blabla} (subs);
    \draw[to] (subs) -- node[midway,above] {blabla}
     node[midway,below] {blabla} (clickdetectado);
     \draw[to] (subs) -- node[midway,left] {blablabla\\blablablabla}
     (clicknodetectado);
     \draw[to] (clicknodetectado) -- node[midway,above] {blablablabla} node[midway,below] {blablabla} (acc_bypass);
     \draw[to, name path=okarc] (clickdetectado) to [out = -50, in = -90, looseness=2.2] node[midway,above] {blablabla} node[midway,below] {blablabla} (parobox);
     \path[overlay,name path=byline] (acc_bypass.south) -- ++(-120:5cm);
     \draw[semithick, line cap=round, name intersections={of=okarc and byline}]
       (acc_bypass.south) to [out=-90, in=30] (intersection-1);
     %\draw[to] (acc_bypass) to [out = -50, in = -90, looseness=1.2] (parobox);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- Both lines are ending with the same input angle at the south east corner of `preparobox`. Two arrow heads are probably not looking too good, thus I let the
  lines end 3 pt before without arrow head and added an arrow line from 3 pt to the south east corner. Since the box has rounded corners, I have reduced `shorten >` to 0 pt.
- As target for the lower line I have used the intersection between the line from "OK" (`clickdetectado`) to `parobox` and an invisible straight line from `acc_bypass.south` with angle `-120`. The intersection point is then calculated with the help of library `intersections`.